# Set Element size on window resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, window-resize

I have this basic event handler

```
window.addEventListener("resize", adjustSize);
```

where everything works as expected until some more sophisticated design with grid and flex comes into play: I prepared minimal testing example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h4fa9qzc/) (see the code below). Then resizing the window by dragging its side works as expected, but discontinuous resizing (maximize button) causes the resized element is a bit misplaced (the end of the bar doesn't reach the outer side of the box border).

So I guess that the parent element is resized, then the resize handler fires, and then it is resized a bit more by adjusting other elements (I test on latest Chrome and Opera, Windows 7). And indeed, delaying the handler a bit solves the problem:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", ()=>setTimeout(adjustSize,10));
```

However, delaying too little (1ms) doesn't help. **Is there a way to solve it by design?**

```js
function adjustWidth() {
  bar.style.width = box.offsetWidth + 'px';
  bar.style.height = box.offsetHeight + 'px';
}
adjustWidth();
window.addEventListener("resize", adjustWidth);
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr); }
#box { box-sizing: border-box; border: 1em solid green; grid-column: 1 / span 9; }
#bar { position: absolute; box-sizing: border-box; }
#bar { display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: column; }
.sep { background: black; flex: 0 0 0.25em; }
.board:first-child { flex: 0 0 50%; }
.board:last-child { flex: 1 0 auto; }
```

```html
<div id="bar">
  <div class="board"></div>
  <div class="sep"></div>
  <div class="board"></div>
</div>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: I think that forcing the browser to resize its elements continuesly it's not the best thing to ask from your browser. 
You could use a global variable e.g.: MyTimeoutId to keep the value setTimeout returns and cancel the previous timeout every time a resize is performing (cancelTimeout). This way you will resize your elements when you really stop resizing.
Hope it helps

Comment: @batspy nice idea, but I tried `clearTimeout(timer); timer = setTimeout(adjustWidth);` in the resize handler without success.

Comment: You could have a look at "debouncing" or "throttling", e. g. here is a nice post with a sample code: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function. If your changes can be done in 10ms, this is great because you may achieve smooth 60fps, but I reckon it's not really important during resize, so feel free to set the timeout to something like 100ms or even more if needed.